# macOS High Sierra Edit Kext

Tags: macos, core-audio, macos-high-sierra, kernel-extension

A while ago I was digging around in the kexts provided with macOS High Sierra, specifically AppleHDA.kext.

The audio driver appears to implement a DSP chain with some rather complicated signal processing going on. In particular, there is a great deal of dynamic range compression applied to the output as well as other things I'd like to experiment with removing.

There are a large number of configuration plists inside, some of which I suppose may apply to my model of MacBook Pro (MacBookPro13,2). I have been able to narrow down which four are likely to be the one that controls the sound system on my machine, and how to edit it to get what I want.

However, after much effort editing the kext, it will not load properly after being repacked. This is supposedly due to kext signing, and I have tried removing the signature altogether and disabling SIP, but both options do not work. Wondering what some suggestions for further exploration would be.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try loading the kext manually using `kextutil`.. this can give you a starting point about why the kext doesn't go up. Also, perhaps you could  add the output here for further analysis.